# Bitcoin opening and closing times

Tags: exchanges

What time does the Bitcoin market open and close?

Also, I've just joined Cryptorobot365 which claims to win 9/10 trades, but I'm still losing money on my account after 4 hours, albeit only £4. Can somebody please help, as I've never done this before?

Comment: "which claims to win 9/10 trades" Come on! That's 100% scam.

Answer (score 4):

There's no "the Bitcoin market".  Bitcoin is traded on many different exchanges.  As far as I know, all of them allow trades 24 hours a day, every day.  Unlike traditional stock exchanges, they don't ever close.

> ive just joined Cryptorobot365 which claims to win 9/10 trades

Any service which makes such claims is a scam.  Get out while you can.